# Is there an expanded Draconic bloodline for sorcerers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer

Looking at the [Draconic Bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/draconic-bloodline) it only includes the base dragon types. Is there any expanded list anywhere including the other newer dragon types?

Official lists are preferred but homebrew is also welcome as well. I've already seen the 3rd-party Faerie Dragon bloodline in the [list of bloodlines](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did more research and still was not able to find an expanded list anywhere.

So I took the time to look through all of the newer dragons and compile a list of the new and the original and what their breath weapons are. The list can be found linked below. I have comments enabled so if I missed any dragons feel free to comment and tell me what I missed.

[Expanded List](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EbPrKEuTVdgCE1onrN52foK5YhTt0zcEMhy--_Tk5WY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5):

I've searched and have found nothing as far as an official list. This is one of those scenarios where a home brew option is very viable. The chromatic or metallic dragon type is there to determine two things: Your elemental type, and your breath shape. So as long as your breath shape is either 30-foot cone, or 60-foot line and consists of one of the four elements: Acid, Cold, Electricity, Fire. You should be good!

Any other customization's beyond that such as picking two element types: Electric for Resistance, Acid for Weapons and breath, would be something you would have to talk to your DM about.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I made a list though so I posted that as the answer.